# Forward type not resolved - Lazarus FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to use an external library from Pascal that I have successfully used from C before. In order to use this library I have been provided a .h file, a .dll file and a .lib file.

I converted the .h file using the h2pas utility but I am getting the following errors (which I suspect are linker-related):

```
Error: (5009) Forward type not resolved "XPRSbranchobject"
```

This appears to be the offending line:

```
type
    ...
    XPRSbranchobject = ^xo_user_branch_entity_s ;
```

How do I let Lazarus know that `xo_user_branch_entity_s` is part of the external library?

Comment: You can't. You should declare, somewhere, the type "xo_user_branch...". You can do it directly in the source, or another unit, but you can't use the library: freepascal uses "units", not "libraries". Maybe you don't need to really dereference that pointer or allocate space; if so, declaring "type xo_user_... : pointer" (or whatever type) is enough.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would do that without having access to the library source or even knowing what "xo_user..." even is. I feel like maybe I could write a wrapper C library for this, but I'd like to avoid going this route if possible

Comment: If you don't have the source, you don't know the details of the type. Maybe you don't need them?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. Like you said, I don't need to know the details. Can I simply forward declare xo_user_branch_entity_s  as pointer?  would it be like type xo_user... : pointer; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write:

```
type
  xo_user_branch_entity_s = record
    a: integer;     // <-- probably redundant
  end;
  XPRSbranchobject = ^xo_user_branch_entity_s;
```

You must be sure you never (de)allocate such object (the record, either directly or via pointer); if the sources tries to access internal members, the compiler will complain.

This implies that allocation/deallocation is done by the DLL.

It should (could?) work...

Comment: Well.. this did indeed help compile. I will continue working on it and see if this even works at runtime! hah thank you very much!!

Comment: Update: this does indeed work.

Comment: It is a bit of a convention to declare such opague structures without any fields, so type xo_user... = record end;  causing  sizeof(xo_user..)=0.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, thank you for pointing out that. I put a member in the record just to be sure that the compiler would not think "this record takes no memory", leading maybe to unexpected behavior, also because a C external module is involved. You clarified a doubt.